# Running proc neural inside a loop

Tags: sas

I have 10 datasets all same x and y but different observations for x and y in each dataset. Each dataset has 120 observations.

I am running proc neural on this dataset but I have to do this manually. Each time I have to change the data= ....and dmdbcat=..... option to include the correct dataset (10 times) and run Proc dmdb and Proc Neural,

Is there a way to to automate this ? Can this Proc Dmdb and Proc Neural run inside a loop so that it can pick up the right dataset iteratively and not have me do this manually ?

Comment: You should look into [macros](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543755.htm) to do automate this process.  You will need knowledge of macro variables as well

Answer (score 1):

You could use the macro language to do this.

But just about every SAS PROC supports a BY statement, which is much more efficient than looping over a list of datasets.

Suggest you combine the datasets:

```
data all;
  set data1 data2 data3 ... indsname=dsn;
  datasetname=dsn;
run;
```

Then analyze:

```
proc neural data=all;
  by datasetname;
run;
```